# Machine translator giving only on character as output for all the words

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, nlp

I had trained a machine translation model using 1.4 million examples.( hindi to english ). strangely the loss plateaus at the same point 0.8301 and while trying the inference the output is always the same no matter what the input is. i am using GRU both in encoder and decoder.

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units,
                                return_sequences=True,
                                return_state=True,
                                recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
# @tf.function(
#     input_signature=[[
#         tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 55], dtype=tf.int32), 
#         tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, embedding_dim], dtype=tf.float32)
#         ]]
# )
# @tf.function
def call(self, inputs):
    x, hidden = inputs
    x = self.embedding(x)
    print(x.shape)
    print(hidden.shape)
    output, state = self.gru(x, initial_state = hidden)
    return output, state

def model(self):
    a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(55))
    b = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256))
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=self.call(a, b))

def initialize_hidden_state(self):
    return tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units))

class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

def call(self, query, values):
    # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
    # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
    # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
    # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
    query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

    # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
    # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
    score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
        self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

    # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

    # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
    context_vector = attention_weights * values
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

    return context_vector, attention_weights

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, batch_sz):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.dec_units = dec_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.dec_units,
                                return_sequences=True,
                                return_state=True,
                                recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')

    # used for attention
    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.dec_units)

# @tf.function(
#     input_signature=[[
#         tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.int32), 
#         tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, embedding_dim], dtype=tf.float32),
#         tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 55, embedding_dim], dtype=tf.float32)
#         ]]
# )
# @tf.function
def call(self, inputs):
    x, hidden, enc_output = inputs
    # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(hidden, enc_output)

    # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(x)

    # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

    # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
    output, state = self.gru(x)

    # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
    output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[2]))

    # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
    x = self.fc(output)

    return x, state, attention_weights

def model(self):
    a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1))
    b = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256))
    c = tf.keras.Input(shape=(55, 256))
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[a, b, c], outputs=self.call(a, b, c))

BATCH_SIZE = 8

embedding_dim = 256
units = 256
vocab_inp_size = len(inp_lang.word_index)+1
vocab_tar_size = len(targ_lang.word_index)+1

target_tensor_train)).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
trainTextGenerator = DataGenerator().sequentialImageGenerator('training',trainData,trainTarget,BATCH_SIZE)
testTextGenerator = DataGenerator().sequentialImageGenerator('testing',testData,testTarget,BATCH_SIZE)
```

what are the possible reasons due to which the output is same all the time?

Comment: You can try the classical NN debugging strategies (see [this](https://twitter.com/karpathy/status/1013244313327681536), [this](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) and [this](http://josh-tobin.com/assets/pdf/troubleshooting-deep-neural-networks-01-19.pdf)), e.g. overfitting to one single batch.

Comment: the links helped a lot. more over the data set had a lot of issues